# WCF service operations to return an object graph

Tags: linq, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a WCF service Operation, I'd like it to return an object graph rather than a simple list of objects.  Is there some magic LinQ to do this?

Thanks

A bit more info is possibly needed:

I have a couple of entities:

StockableItem
+ Id
+ Code

Stock
+ Id
+ Location
+ Qty

StockableItem->Stock is a 1..* relationship.

and I am failing with this linq:

from si in svc.StockableItems.Include("Stock")
join s in svc.Stock on si.Id equals s.Id 
where s.Location == 1
select si

and several variations.

I'm hoping the service operation will be able to return something like this:

StockableItem - ID=213, Code=xxx
StockableItem - ID=214, Code=xxx2
    + Stock - ID=214, Location=1, Qty=3
StockableItem - ID=215, Code=xxx3
StockableItem - ID=216, Code=xxx4
    + Stock - ID=216, Location=1, Qty=6

i.e. To return all StockableItems along with the Stock entries for the given location. It's pretty much just a left outer join:

Select * from StockableItems si
Left outer join Stock s ON si.Id = s.Id and s.Location = @Location

but turned into an object graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear; sounds like you'd ideally want an OData solution. You can't return an object graph from a WCF Data services service operation called from an OData query. You can get a flat list of objects but then need to use $expand to get the object graph. In your case $expand won't work, it'll return all the stock instances for whichever StockItems pass the filter.

I think your best bet would be to create a view in your DB (I assume you have a table of locations?)

```
    SELECT       si.Id, Locations.Location 
    FROM         StockableItem AS si  
    CROSS JOIN   Locations
```

In your entity model, add this view as an entity (called XXX say) and set up navigation properties between it and your StockableItem and Stock entities.

Now you can run OData queries like

```
.../XXX?$expand=StockableItem,Stock&$filter=isof(Stock,'YourModelName.Stock') and Location eq 1
```

It's not the exact object graph you were after but, unless you want to start adding links client side, it's the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the query above exactly what it is that you want to do. With the WCF DS client you can add where clauses that drill through properties:

```
from si in svc.StockableItems
where si.Stock.Location == 1
select si
// Results in something like http://services.odata.org/Experimental/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter=Category/Name eq 'Beverages'
```

You can also explicitly do eager loading with the Expand method or by including that in your projection:

```
svc.StockableItems.Expand("Stock").Where(si => si.Stock.Location == 1) // OR
from si in svc.StockableItems
where si.Stock.Location == 1
select si, si.Stock
// Results in something like http://services.odata.org/Experimental/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter=Category/Name eq 'Beverages'&$expand=Category
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Mark, I have updated the original question with some more information.

Comment: Did you try the `Expand` method above? I'm not sure if we're disconnected in what you're looking for or if maybe you missed that part of the answer. `Expand` is the WCF DS equivalent of `Include` in EF.

Comment: As I understand it, the Expand method is a member of DataServiceQuery<T> and so, will be converted into an OData query? I'd already given up trying to run this query from the client, since I couldn't write an OData query which would do the job. So, my service operation doesn't have a refernce to be able to use Expand (if i add it, will I not be creating an OData query?) also, since StockableItems->Stock is a 1..* relationship, si.Stock.Location == 1 won't work and I'm not sure what LinQ would?

Comment: Expand is part of the client-side of the API, but you can definitely do it (at least, what I think you want to do) from the client side. I glossed over the part where it's a `1:*` relationship, sorry about that. Your two options in that case are to reverse the query and start from Stock and expand StockableItem (I can update my answer above to that effect) or to use the Any/All support if it's a V3 service you're hitting. In general I would recommend against trying to do things in a service operation unless that's REALLY the right answer, which it doesn't seem to be in this case.

Comment: It can be a V3 service if that will solve the problem. Currently my OData queries either return all StockableItems and all Stock, irrespective of the stock location, or just those StockableItems for which there is stock at the location. I'll have a look at Any/All support in V3, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Found some time to come back to this; I have tried using the any/all support in V3 but haven't yet come up with the OData query which I need.  I need all stockable items, irrespective of whether they have stock at a particular location but, I do need to expand and return any associated stock at the given location.